# SQL - Sum then divide by zero problems

Tags: sql, count, rounding, zero

I'm attempting to sum 2 columns and divide one by the other however I'm facing problems when dividing by zero.

The maths is essentially Sum(a)/Sum(b)

My code:

```
SELECT
      SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) as Quantity,   

      SUM(inventory.TotalValueOutstanding) as ExtValue,

      (SELECT NULLIF(sum(Inventory.TotalValueOutstanding), 0) /
      NULLIF(SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding), 0)  FROM Inventory)  as AcctValue

FROM Inventory 
GROUP BY inventory.TotalValueOutstanding
```

My expected result:

```
| Quantity | Extvalue  | AcctValue
|  -10.00  | -92.00    |  0.11
|   13.00  | 0.00      |  0
|   0.00   | 0.00      |  0
|   2.00   | 16.00     |  0.125
```

My actual output:

```
| Quantity | Extvalue  | AcctValue
|  -10.00  | -92.00    |  76.603066544004906470
|   13.00  | 0.00      |  76.603066544004906470
|   0.00   | 0.00      |  76.603066544004906470
|   2.00   | 16.00     |  76.603066544004906470
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of is if you are grouping by total outstanding, then if two totals are the same, it will end up grouping them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how these are being grouped, but I would assume that it is some kind of item or ID? For the sake of argument, I've called that ColumnID, but you can replace it with what you are actually using (e.g. InventoryItemName?)

You can then try this, which just checks if quantity outstanding is 0. If it is then the answer is just 0, else calculate the formula as normal.

```
SELECT
   Inventory.ColumnID,
   SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) as Quantity,   

   SUM(inventory.TotalValueOutstanding) as ExtValue,

   IIF(SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) = 0
        ,0
        ,isnull(sum(Inventory.TotalValueOutstanding), 0) /
           sum(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding)
       ) as AcctValue
FROM 
   Inventory 
GROUP BY
   Inventory.ColumnID
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(i.QuantityOutstanding) as Quantity,   
       SUM(i.TotalValueOutstanding) as ExtValue,
       (NULLIF(SUM(i.TotalValueOutstanding), 0) /
               NULLIF(SUM(i.QuantityOutstanding), 0)
       ) as AcctValue
FROM Inventory i
GROUP BY i.TotalValueOutstanding ;
```

I find the double `NULLIF()` a bit confusing.  This might be clearer using `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(i.QuantityOutstanding) as Quantity,   
       SUM(i.TotalValueOutstanding) as ExtValue,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(i.QuantityOutstanding) = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE SUM(i.TotalValueOutstanding) /                   
                  SUM(i.QuantityOutstanding)
        END) as AcctValue
FROM Inventory i
GROUP BY i.TotalValueOutstanding ;
```